# GFCI and switch in one box, separate functions

Tags: gfi

[image]I have a GFCI in a box and a light switch that controls an exhaust fan, and the switch works but the GFCI doesn't, and that GFCI is linked to other plugs that no longer work. Can some one tell me how to hook the GFCI up the the power line without disturbing the switch or making the switch control the plugs. How do I connect the power to it and the switch separately . I don't know how to run the wire or a pigtail off the main line to get them all to work properly

Comment: Struggling to understand "*no longer*" works combined with the question about how to install new wiring.  Is it currently wired in a way that once worked?  What was in this box before you changed it and how was it wired?

Comment: Have you tried re-seting the GFCI?  The power must be on for the unit to re-set.

Comment: The cable connected to the switch looks like it's probably a switch loop (old wire), and therefore on a separate circuit.  I don't know how you would be able to have other outlets on the same circuit as the GFCI when there's only one cable—that we can see—connected to it.

Comment: I only see one cable to the GFCI.  Presumably, that is the line feeding it from the other outlets you refer to (is that right?).  If so, the GFCI won't affect those outlets; they're not getting power for some other reason (breaker open?).  Are you undertaking rewiring in more than this location?  Lot's of unknowns make it hard to figure how to help!

Answer (score 2):

You are telling us the GFCI doesn't work and other plugs don't work.

There is only one cable going to the GFCI.

The logical conclusion is that the circuit feeding the GFCi, and most likely the other outlets, is open.

Find the breaker that is tripped and re-set it. (Breakers must be turned all the way to the off position and then turned on.)

One other possibility is the other outlets and the GFCI shown are receiving power from another GFCI and that is open.